# Unity - type name 'Rigidbody2D' could not be found in the namespace 'UnityEngine' after upgraded project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started Unity and I am following a tutorial on Youtube. Everything was working fine until I upgraded my project from 2018.4.13f1 to 2018.4.14f1. And now, I have an error with Rigidbody2D:

> The type name 'Rigidbody2D' could not be found in the namespace
>   'UnityEngine'. This type has been forwarded to assembly
>   'UnityEngine.Physics2DModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' Enable the built in package 'Physics 2D' in the
>   Package Manager window to fix this error.

So, following some similar [errors](https://forum.unity.com/threads/no-package-manager-in-window-menu-for-2018-2.539851/), I deleted the Packages folder. However, now I still have an error but a bit different:

> The type name 'Rigidbody2D' could not be found in the namespace
>   'UnityEngine'. This type has been forwarded to assembly
>   'UnityEngine.Physics2DModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' Enable the built in package 'Physics 2D' in the
>   Package Manager window to fix this error.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class TapController : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might just be missing that package in your project

Just import it by going top File Menu in Unity and selecting ***Window -> Package Manager***

Then search for ***Physics 2D*** and make sure that it's enabled

[image]

Comment: There is no Package Manager in Window

Comment: Hmm that's odd. What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Version 2018.4.14f1

Comment: You might have run into the [problem mentioned here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/package-manager-is-missing.557854/) If you don't have any hard requirements I'd recommend upgrading to Unity 2019 where they seem to have fixed that issue without requiring any workarounds

Comment: Alright, I will try a new install then and keep you in touch

Comment: In case you're still having issues with it showing up you might need to install the **.NET Core cross-platform development** component mentioned in the post I linked earlier

Comment: Alright, I installed a fresh version of Unity 2019.2.17f1 and now I have a Package Manager but I don't have Physics 2D

Comment: Another solution is to update the manifest.json in Packages folder

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Editor Package version Update from the Unity Package Manager for a better Visual Studio integration.

Answer (score -2):

I also encountered this problem today. I found that my problem was that the license was not set. I set a personal license, and that resolved the error.